# Bind multiple ports to multiple url with nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm newbie using nginx. I was using Docker to deploy some apps in differents port. No problems with deployment. I can set hostname one app but the problem is when try to set hostname to the other app. For example.

App_1:

- hostname: http://app.1.com
- Ports to expose: 8080, 5000

App_2: (problem here)

- hostname: http://app.2.com
- Ports to expose: 8081, 5001

When access to http://app.1.com is no problem, but http://app.2.com throws an error. If access by IP and port http://192.168.1.x:8081 then shows something.

All runs locally and read that nginx can do that but searching in google, can't find some clearly. I hope you can help me.

Thanks!!

Comment: You need to share your nginx configuration, Dockerfile, and how you are running Docker.

Comment: Can you show how you are configuring nginx?

Comment: Sorry, i don't have nginx configuration yet. I want to see what kind of configuration I need to use and have the result that I describe above.